# how to renew an expired "let's encrypt" certificate?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I am "newbie" I installed a "nginx" and "https" with this tutorial:
https://www.supinfo.com/articles/single/3558-installer-certificat-ssl-nginx-avec-let-s-encrypt.

my domains worked well and were accessible in https but I turned off my server too long and left the certificate expired.

now I can not renew my certificates because the command line does not work if the certificate has expired how to do it? Thank you

the error message

Attempting to renew cert from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/info.fr.conf produced an unexpected error: Failed authorization procedure. info.fr (http-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Fetching http://info.fr/.well-known/acme-challenge/PwznYVREcdpBsSMDPhP_lp3s1bqbidN83z1lyNXm3Yc: Connection refused. Skipping.

Comment: Does your site works well (on the http)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove you letsencrypt folder and try to reinstall certificates like a first time

```
 sudo rm -rf /etc/letsencrypt
```

this is the easiest way

2. If prev way is not for you:

Comment out all strings that use certificates

Change line `listen *:443 ssl;` to `listen *:80;`

Restart nginx

```
service nginx restart
```

Try to renew certificates

Again change line `listen *:80` to `listen *:443 ssl;`

Uncomment all lines that use certificates

Restart nginx again

Comment: use `sudo service nginx restart` if not as root user